# Redis Sorted Set trends

Tags: redis, sortedset

I'm currently working on implementing a game leaderboard using Redis sorted sets.

My question is whether you can extract any information from the trend. For example, many games show whether you're trending upward or downward like so:

[image]

Do Redis sorted sets have the ability to easily return trends? Or does it have any memory of previous ranks which would make this easy to determine? Or would I need to add custom logic to achieve this?

Comment: No.. No.. Yes..

Comment: hello, have you found a way to implement this?

Comment: unfortunately no, we decided to cut the feature and just went with a standard leaderboard. Seemed like we would've needed to create our own system to track this.